# qemu-system-i386: Could not allocate clusters for qcow2 header and refcount table: Bad address

Tags: android, emulation, qemu

Can't start Android emulator on Mac 10.12.6. I noticed one output might be the cause:
qemu-system-i386: Could not allocate clusters for qcow2 header and refcount table: Bad address

Below is more output with -verbose and -debug all option:

```
emulator: Starting QT main loop

emulator: Android qemu version 27.1.7.0 (build_id 4581633) (CL:b5ec07662db0f9d8644e5fbda7040053a8741bfd)

emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: android_qemud_init
qemu-system-i386: Could not allocate clusters for qcow2 header and refcount table: Bad address
emulator: Done with QEMU main loop
emulator: found skin 'nexus_6' in directory: /Users/dzhang/Library/Android/sdk/skins/
emulator: (metrics::NullMetricsWriter) created
emulator: (metrics::NullMetricsReporter) created
emulator: (metrics::reportConditional) ignoring
emulator: skin_winsys_get_window_pos
emulator: skin_winsys_get_window_pos: x=0 y=0
emulator: Finished QT main loop
```

I googled around and didn't find anything relevant. Per code here: https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/block/qcow2.c
Seems it failed to open image.

Update: created a new image and got the same error message. The emulator crashed this time and below is the problem report:

```
Operating system: Mac OS X
                  10.12.6 16G1212
CPU: amd64
     family 6 model 70 stepping 1
     8 CPUs

Crash reason:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS / KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS
Crash address: 0xd0
Process uptime: 1 seconds

Thread 10 (crashed)
 0  qemu-system-i386 + 0x354677
    rax = 0x00000000000000d0   rdx = 0x0000000000000000
    rcx = 0x00007fb1ea8007c0   rbx = 0x0000700001029000
    rsi = 0x0000000000000000   rdi = 0x000000010eeb8db0
    rbp = 0x0000700001028ef0   rsp = 0x0000700001028ed0
     r8 = 0x0000700000fa8000    r9 = 0x0000000000083000
    r10 = 0x0000000000000001   r11 = 0x0000000000000206
    r12 = 0x000000010d34a660   r13 = 0x0000000000009a17
    r14 = 0x00000000180008ff   r15 = 0x00007fb1ea8007c0
    rip = 0x000000010d34a677
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
```

Seems like a qemu issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out the qemu is blocked by our cooperate security software Cylance since it detects sensitive memory reading operation. Need to talk with IT team to change the policy to unblock it.

Comment: I disregarded this answer out of hand but turns out this was the exact cause for me as well.  We now use Cylance that silently blocked qem-system and it took me days to figure this out.

Comment: I just had the same issue/solution. For Mac Users with Cylance installed, there should be a shield icon on the top-right (where your date/time is located). Click the shield > Show Details > Exploits. From here you will see a record for each time Cylance blocked you if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that your QCOW2 guest disk image is corrupt. Try with a known-good disk image?

Comment: The images were downloaded two days ago. Tried with both Nexus 6 and Pixel images and the same result. I even tried with x86 64 system image and got the same error, except qemu-system-i386 changed to qemu-system-x86_64. Not sure if it's a qemu issue or some system permission related.